# Is every museum in Washington DC free to visit?

Tags: fees-and-charges, museums, washington-dc

I want to know that if I want to go to the museums in Washington DC, Is it free to enter? Or there is any fee ?

Comment: Is there any city in the world where this is the case?

Comment: @choster i don't know. I've just heard about Washington DC.

Comment: @choster most museums in London are free.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The majority of the museums in Washington DC are run by the [Smithsonian](http://www.si.edu/), and offer free entry to everyone (with optional donations being accepted).

There are also a number of non-Smithsonian museums, such as the [US Holocaust Memorial Museum](http://www.ushmm.org/) (free, but requires a timed ticket for entry), [Newseum](http://newseum.org/) (not free), and the [International Spy Museum](http://spymuseum.org/) (also not free).